# Trying to run example parrot script: "ValueError: Failed to load delegate from edgetpu.dll"

Tags: python, google-coral, pycoral

I have been trying to run the very first demo script (parrot). This error seems to indicate it could not load the edgetpu.dll. But it is in the system32 folder so I'm now wondering if there is a known solution.

I am wondering whether I should be running Python 3.9 64 or whether there is a mismatch between edgetpu and python.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1992]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\chris>cd C:\Users\chris\coral\pycoral

C:\Users\chris\coral\pycoral>python examples/classify_image.py --model     test_data/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_inat_bird_quant_edgetpu.tflite --labels test_data/inat_bird_labels.txt --input test_data/parrot.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tflite_runtime\interpreter.py", line 160, in load_delegate
  delegate = Delegate(library, options)
File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tflite_runtime\interpreter.py", line 119, in __init__
  raise ValueError(capture.message)
ValueError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\chris\coral\pycoral\examples\classify_image.py", line 121, in <module>
  main()
File "C:\Users\chris\coral\pycoral\examples\classify_image.py", line 71, in main
  interpreter = make_interpreter(*args.model.split('@'))
File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pycoral\utils\edgetpu.py", line 87, in make_interpreter
  delegates = [load_edgetpu_delegate({'device': device} if device else {})]
File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pycoral\utils\edgetpu.py", line 52, in load_edgetpu_delegate
  return tflite.load_delegate(_EDGETPU_SHARED_LIB, options or {})
File "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tflite_runtime\interpreter.py", line 162, in load_delegate
  raise ValueError('Failed to load delegate from {}\n{}'.format(
ValueError: Failed to load delegate from edgetpu.dll
```

I ran this

```
python examples/classify_image.py --model test_data/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_inat_bird_quant_edgetpu.tflite --labels test_data/inat_bird_labels.txt --input test_data/parrot.jpg
```

in a Windows CMD shell

Answer (score 0):

OK this was too simple. The connector to the USB Accelerator is a bit sticky and I had to push it in more firmly.